# Do you know any ruby lexers I could use in an application?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I would need lexers for as many programming languages I could get, and I would need them to be written in ruby. Do you know any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [RACC](http://i.loveruby.net/en/projects/racc/) be useful to you?

You can combine it with [REX](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/rex/) to generate your lexer.

Comment: I don't want to have to write the lexers myself. I would like them to be ready made.

Comment: Grammars exist for a lot of different languages. Just google for LALR grammars for a given language.

Answer (score 2):

RACC is not a lexer. It is a parser generator.
REX is a lexer, and it is ready made, it is a ruby implementation of lex.

Theres another lexer for ruby.
I think it's called ruby-lex.

Comment: FYI for anyone else who is interested: I have used RACC & REX together to create an interpreter, and they worked. Not too different from YACC and Lex.

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit you, but can I suggest you to take a look at [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for Python? I understand it might fall outside the scope of your question but this tool has support for a [ton of languages](http://pygments.org/languages/) and it provides a command-line tool so you can call it from Ruby.

Albino is a small Ruby wrapper for using Pygments from Ruby: http://gist.github.com/82824